# Issue with Title when converting seasonal_decompose plot to Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, statsmodels

I ran a seasonal decomposition using the Python library `statsmodels`.

I then successfully converted the resulting plot to a Plotly object using `plotly.tools.mpl_to_plotly`.

However, I cannot find a way to correctly format the chart title. I have tried setting it before the conversion and adding it after, but it always is either partly cut off or just appears in the middle of the plot.

Find the code block below:

```
seasonal_decomposition = seasonal_decompose(prices, model = 'additive')
seasonal_decomposition_fig = seasonal_decomposition.plot()
seasonal_decomposition_fig = plotly.tools.mpl_to_plotly(seasonal_decomposition_fig)
seasonal_decomposition_fig.update_layout(width = 1100, height = 500, title = 'Seasonal Decomposition')
```

Here you can see the code block and the subsequent output, with the title cut off. The screenshot is attached below:

[image]

If anyone knows how I could fix this I would be super grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you adjust the margins? you can try passing the argument `margin=dict(t=100)` to the `update_layout` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fig.update_layout(title_text='your title here', title_x=0.5)
```

Reproducible example:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2"))

fig.add_scatter(y=[2, 1, 3], row=1, col=1) 
fig.add_scatter(y=[1, 3, 2], row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(title_text='Your title here', title_x=0.5, showlegend=False)
```

Output:
[image]